# How to print random words in Python and find the most used word

Tags: python

How to print random words in Python and find the most used word

```
import random
a = [
    "python", "Java", "C", "C++", "C#", "Pascal", "Lenovo", "HP", "Dell", "Apple", "Samsung", "CSS", "HTML",
    "Javascript", "PHP", "variable", "list", "set", "dict", "tuple", "tkinter", "opencv2", "random", "requests", "pyttsx3",
    "wolframalpha", "speech_recognition", "pocketsphinx", "pyaudio", "os", "datetime", "wikipedia", "webbrowser",
    "smtplib", "pyautogui", "psutil", "pyjokes", "json", "urllib.parse", "roman", "urllib.request", "translate",
    "Google", "Brave", "Firefox", "Opera", "Yandex", "Alice", "Unity", "Asus", "Acer", "Jarvis AI", "VR", "Atom",
    "VS code", "Sublime text", "Pycharm", "Intellij IDEA", "Code blocks", "Access", "Publisher", "Outlook", "Teams",
    "Onenote", "Word", "Power Point", "Excel", "Forms", "Sway", "To Do"
]
n = int(input("Enter a number: "))

if n <= 70:
    for i in range(n):
        b = random.choice(a)
        print(b)
        a.count(b)    
else:
    print("Words exceeded the limit. You can get up to 70 words.")
```

Comment: what is the error you're receiving? see [ask] a question.

Comment: And what are you going to do when there is multiple most used words?

Comment: Here's the idea. You have to store random words chosen in a list and after that check for most frequent word. So now complete your code.

Comment: I want to print most used word.

Comment: This will help you https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-find-most-frequent-element-in-a-list/

Comment: I want to find the most taken word in the top list and write it down

Comment: Please add a example output.

Comment: what do you mean by most used word? does it mean most used word from the list, or character or what?

Comment: Like that: n = 5 word: Java, python, C++, C#, C++. output most used word is C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

```
import random
from collections import Counter

a = [
    "python", "Java", "C", "C++", "C#", "Pascal", "Lenovo", "HP", "Dell", "Apple", "Samsung", "CSS", "HTML",
    "Javascript", "PHP", "variable", "list", "set", "dict", "tuple", "tkinter", "opencv2", "random", "requests", "pyttsx3",
    "wolframalpha", "speech_recognition", "pocketsphinx", "pyaudio", "os", "datetime", "wikipedia", "webbrowser",
    "smtplib", "pyautogui", "psutil", "pyjokes", "json", "urllib.parse", "roman", "urllib.request", "translate",
    "Google", "Brave", "Firefox", "Opera", "Yandex", "Alice", "Unity", "Asus", "Acer", "Jarvis AI", "VR", "Atom",
    "VS code", "Sublime text", "Pycharm", "Intellij IDEA", "Code blocks", "Access", "Publisher", "Outlook", "Teams",
    "Onenote", "Word", "Power Point", "Excel", "Forms", "Sway", "To Do"
]
n = int(input("Enter a number: "))
new=[]
if n <= 70:
    for i in range(n):
        b = random.choice(a)
        new.append(b)

else:
    print("Words exceeded the limit. You can get up to 70 words.")

c = Counter(new)
word=c.most_common(1)[0]
print("mamximum used element is",word[0],"having length",word[1])
```

Using Counter to get the most common element and using random.choice() to append a new random list.

Answer (score -2):

Use print() function and import randword.

Comment: Mr Keprins, please provide more detail in your answer.